# Trouble starting sandbox and navigator in the Quickstart Tutorial

Tags: daml

I am working through the [Digital Asset quickstart guide](https://docs.daml.com/packages/quickstart/index.html).  I am receiving some warning messages when starting Sandbox:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil (file:/home/vantage/.da/packages/sandbox/6.0.0/lib/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

So too when I start Navigator:

```
Version 1.1.1
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil (file:/home/vantage/.da/packages/navigator/1.1.1/navigator-1.1.1.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Should I be concerned that something is wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

this warning is because gRPC uses some operations, which are deprecated above Java 8. I assume you are using a fairly recent JRE, that's why you see this error.

They fixed the problem about a month ago and it takes time until the change propagates up the stack into higher level libraries, so it can be included in the Sandbox and Navigator.

See: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/3781

TL;DR: Ignore the warning for now, it's harmless and will be fixed. :)